# How can I build a regex to exclude all, except letters and numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function

I need to return a filtered string with "a1a" from the following function.

I've tried several regexes but nothing. On top of all, I can't use methods (part of the challenge).

```
let extractPassword = function(arr) {
  let toString = "";
  for (let i in arr) {
    if ( arr[i] === /[A - Za - z0 -9]/) {
      toString += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(toString);
  }
};

extractPassword(["a", "-", "~", "1", "a", "/"]);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have these spaces in your regex? Just why?

Comment: Try to remove the spaces in your regular expression... `/A-Za-z0-9/`.

Comment: You can't use methods, but the first line of your code is the creation of a method?  Can you clarify this requirement?

Comment: You can use a service like https://regex101.com/ to test and refine your regex.

Comment: I can't use methods live slice() or  .map() etc... I need to create a funct to do just that...

Comment: the spaces are added automatically by my VS code. It's an extension that does that...

Comment: I did used a regex service, but nothing... It seems like my VSCode doesn't recognize  regexes...

Comment: As `arr[i]` is a string, it'll never be equal to your regex. To test a string against a regex, you **have** to use one of the methods of `RegEx`'s or `String`'s prototype

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: A string cannot be `===` to a regular expression object.  You have to use one of regex's methods, such as `.test(...)`, to determine if the string matches the regex.

Comment: you mean like this? 
    if (arr[i].match(/A - Za - z0 -9/gi)) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you just want to take the characters that match your regex and join them?

```js
let extractPassword = arr => arr.filter(v => v.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]/)).join('');
  
let pw = extractPassword(["a", "-", "~", "1", "a", "/"]);
console.log(pw);
```

If you mean `filter` and `join` are prohibited, then you can reinvent them trivially:

```js
let extractPassword = arr => {
  let r = '';
  for (let v of arr)
    if (v.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]/))
      r += v;
  return r;
};

let pw = extractPassword(["a", "-", "~", "1", "a", "/"]);
console.log(pw);
```

Comment: The second one solved it. Thanks a lot for the help.I'm still a noob...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems.

1. Remove the spaces inside the regex.  `A-Z` and `A - Z` do not mean the same thing.  The first indicates you want to match any letter between A and Z inclusive.  The latter indicates you want to match `A`, `-`, or `Z`.
2. Use the `test(...)` method on the regex object to determine whether the string matches the regular expression pattern.  A string cannot ever be equal to the regex object.
3. The `toString` variable is a commonly used method.  This makes your code a little less clear.  I gave it a more appropriate name, `extractedPw`, which better denotes its purpose.
4. You are not returning anything from your method.  The name "*extract* password" suggests it will return an extracted password.

```
let extractPassword = function(arr) {
  let extractedPw = "";
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (/[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(arr[i])) {
      extractedPw += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(extractedPw);
  }
  return extractedPw;
};

extractPassword(["a", "-", "~", "1", "a", "/"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you time and for the perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

String === regular expression doesn't work.

Instead use RegExp.prototype.test()

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Your code could look like this:

```js
let extractPassword = function(arr) {
  let toString = "";
  const regex = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (regex.test(arr[i])) {
      toString += arr[i];
    }
  }
  return toString;
};

console.log(extractPassword(["a", "-", "~", "1", "a", "/"]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function named extractPassword which takes an array of characters (which includes some trash characters) and returns a string with only valid characters (a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It is not clear how this is an answer to the original question. Maybe elaborate a bit...